# Any clue as to why Stack Overflow is loading so slowly?

Tags: support, status-norepro

For the last four days Stack Overflow has been loading extremely slowly for me, some parts load fine, the page *displays* but the links and CSS hover rules (etc) take a significant (1+ second) pause before appearing, I am unable to leave comments on posts because the jQuery (or similar) that runs the comment box does not fire when I click the comment, and likewise I can not vote.

Parts of pages react to my actions but the majority of the site has a significant pause, of over a second, such as CSS hover effects for buttons and some buttons that I know are buttons (such as the home page link) do not show as buttons and do not respond at all.

Even writing this textbox I have issues where the textbox loses focus (although the cursor remains in the text box) and then I have to click and wait 1-2 seconds before this regains focus. Also on the "questions that may already have your answer" section, it takes that Ajax box several seconds to display once I've written my question title.

I am using other websites perfectly fine with no delay and no issues.

I have cleared my browser and also double checked my addons etc, of which I have very few.

Firebug comes back with a small error about `getPreventDefault()` being deprecated,

But my most noticeable issue is that it is impossible to select text to copy from SO or meta.SO.

If I was reading this I would suspect this was my browser, but that other websites of various types all work fine seems to imply it is site specific,

I don't know how best to problem solve this issue. My only thought is that it seems there is some sort of interface such as a JavaScript layer between the screen output and my input, but no idea if this is what's going on or how to detect such things.

issue: 4 days
Firefox: v41
site: stackoverflow.com domain only.
virus scan: clean

Any help or clues on the cause would be appreciated.

edit: for the comment; Firefox automatically updated the version to v41 from holiday.
edit edit: finally managing to click your link, I now understand the support is in reference to SO.  of curiosity I am rolling back to Firefox 40.0.3 to see if this site improves.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Give the standard line on supported browsers is "current version and last 2", I would suspect that the MSE post is out of date and not the browser is unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

My issue has been entirely solved with Stack Overflow site by downloading and reinstalling the version 40.0.3 of Firefox. I have no idea why version 41 of Firefox caused such issues but they are non-existent with the preceding version.

With the nature of browser updates being continual and regular, this seems more like a bug with either: my version of FFv41 (somehow) or *.SO.com site. If anyone else with Firefox Version 41 can give feedback this would be useful.

## EDIT:

My issue has been solved on Version 41 by deleting and creating a new Firefox profile. I have no idea what new profile features caused this upset but setting a new profile seems to have completely solved the problem.

Comment: I don't have any issues with v41. Try upgrading again to see if the issue re-appears. If so, try running with a [clean profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager).

Comment: thanks for that idea @Stijn , I will check out cleaning and using a new profile.

Comment: @Stijn deleting the profile and using a new profile on a new install of version41 seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: 20 years ago you wouldn't know why a program/OS crashed and you would just reboot the computer and if that failed reinstall the software to get rid of problems. Nowadays you don't know why a program misbehaves and you just start with clean settings. Nothing has changed really, only the aggressiveness of what you need to do to get rid of problems :)